# Something that allows admin to distribute tasks to users who may finally see those in their respective dashboards

Tags: php, cms, wordpress, plug-in

I am looking for a solution (eg, plug-in for Wordpress) that facilitates the following:

- Tasks are inputed by a **Data Entry Operator**, which the **Admin** can view in a tabular form. A task may have its *id*, *description*, etc.
- Admin assigns tasks to **clerks** A, B, C, and so on. Preferably, against each row there is some drop down which says *Assign task to* and in the options clerks A, B, C, etc are listed.
- Once clerks A, B, C, etc logs in, he/she sees in his/her dashboard the respective tasks assigned to him/her. He/she has the option to update the *task status* as *complete* when he/she wishes.
- Any user (the admin, the clerks, or the data entry operator) can at any point of time search the *task id* and see its status, and to whom it is assigned.

To summarise:

- There are three types of users - admin, clerks and data entry operators. CMS like Wordpress might be useful to distinguish the various roles, so it's the first thing that came in my mind.
- The functionalities that I need are - data entry, assign jobs, update status of own tasks, and search tasks.

Is there a plug-in or plug-ins for Wordpress or any other solution that facilitates the above?

Note: Though I would prefer Wordpress any other solutions including other PHP CMSs are equally fine. Only thing to note here is that we want to host the solution in a local server.

Comment: This sounds like a bugtracker/issue tracker

Comment: Or google for 'wordpress kanban'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving suggestions in comments and chats, I tried some **help desk softwares**. There are many out there. I found that one such PHP software called **Hesk** meets my needs.

For our needs,

- we created all the users manually.
- created some custom fields.
- created some custom *statuses*. The already existing ones are *resolved*, *on hold*, etc. The system doesn't allow modification on these already existing *statuses* from the front end.